# Why to use DataSet.BeginInit and DataSet.EndInit

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset

Why do we use `DataSet.BeginInit` and `DataSet.EndInit` ?

I have gone through [official msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.begininit.aspx), which says

> Begins the initialization of a DataSet that is used on a form or used
>   by another component.

But i am not able understand how is it useful in real time scenario ? can anyone give me a good example?

Comment: in that documentation it clearly specified that Using the BeginInit and EndInit methods prevents the control from being used before it is fully initialized.

Comment: @Terror.Blade: yes. I could read that. How exactly this helps or doesn't help us. I cannot think of case where control can be used before initializing it.

Comment: The documentation is useless. What it actually does is defer calls to AddRange( ), such as rows and constraints, to until the EndInit( ) is called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are no cases when you have to explicitly call them. They are only used by [the designer environment to prevent the control from being used before it is fully initialized](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/181236/why-use-dataset-begininit-method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I saw the use of BeginInit and EndInit in my colleague's C# code, and the  scenario is just like the description in the following link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3621640/Re-Datatable-BeginInit-and-EndInit.aspx

> If you want to change multiple properties of the DataView object but don’t want the changes to affect the data visible through the DataView until you’ve changed all of the desired properties, you can use the BeginInit and EndInit methods.
>
> For example, say you have a DataView bound to a particular DataTable and you’ve also set the DataView object’s RowFilter property so that only a small fraction of the rows are visible through the DataView. You’re displaying the contents of the DataView on a Windows form using a DataGrid, and based on input from the user you want to change the settings of the DataView object’s Table and RowFilter properties. In this situation, you should enclose the code that changes the DataView object’s properties within calls to the DataView object’s BeginInit and EndInit property to prevent the DataGrid from momentarily displaying all rows from the new DataTable.